# How to extract text of specific tags with multiple occurrences

Tags: beautifulsoup

HTML:

```
"<span class="font-weight-bold color-primary small text-right text-nowrap">29,95 €</span>
```

url = https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Magic/Cards/Bloodstained-Mire?sellerCountry=13&sellerReputation=2&language=1&minCondition=4#articleFilterSellerLocation

I wish to extract the text of 29,95 €.

Currently using BeautifulSoup. However, the page has a table with many other texts like this which I also wish to extract. How do I find all of these tags and extract only the text at the end to a list?

The current code I have tried is:

```
for price in new_page:
    new_page.find("div", class_="table-body")
    price = new_page.find_all("span", attrs="font-weight-bold color-primary small text-right text-nowrap")
    output_price = [x["font-weight-bold color-primary small text-right text-nowrap"] for x in price]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(url):
    params = {
        "sellerCountry": "13",
        "sellerReputation": "2",
        "language": "1",
        "minCondition": "4"
    }
    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    print(soup.select_one('dl.labeled dd:nth-child(6)').text)


main('https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Magic/Cards/Bloodstained-Mire')
```

Output:

```
29,95 €
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, it has opened up a new approach for me to take. I now need to work out how to loop round the sellers list. Thanks again.

Comment: @JakeW22 https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers